# How to deal with a large number of (possibly variable) topic names

Tags: ros, namespace, topic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our system has many sensors, and in the future the number of a particular type of sensor may vary.

Currently our scheme is something like:

```
/sensor/temperature0
/sensor/temperature1
```

but this scales poorly with a large number of temperature sensors. Likewise, if there is a node which is supposed to log all temperature sensor data, it now has to be reconfigured each time the number of temperature sensors changes.

One way to deal with the explosion of sensor numbers is to include an "index" attribute inside the sensor message itself. This way we would only have a single topic

```
/sensor/temperature
```

but this would mean every subscriber which was interested in only one of the temperatures would have to discard all the other messages, resulting in unnecessary overhead and boilerplate code.

Has anyone come up with an elegant solution to this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199678/how-to-deal-with-a-large-number-of-(possibly-variable)-topic-names/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are either going to have the overhead of processing many topics with one subscriber, or processing one topic/subscriber with many subscribers. That's unavoidable in a single node, and I suspect you'd prefer not to have multiple node instances. Personally, I'd opt for many subscribers; one way you might handle this is with a yaml configuration file, a launch file, and a nifty `boost::bind` trick.

I should say explicitly that I haven't run the actual code below, but I do use variations of it, so I know the fundamental idea is sound.

A `sensors.yaml` file (in the root directory of the `sensors` package, as specified in the launch file below) contains a list of topics:

```
# list of sensor topics (need to prepend '/sensor/' to each)
temperature_sensors: [temperature0, temperature1, ...]
```

Note that the following launch file enters the contents of `sensors.yaml` into the parameter server in the node's namespace (which is handy to know if you need to get the information from another node). The `temperature_sensor_set` is used to specify the initial topics to be processed (which can then be modified at run time).

```
<launch>
  <!-- type 'myclass' executable name for 'MyClass' class -->
  <node pkg="sensors" name="sensors" type="myclass" >
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find sensors)/sensors.yaml" />
    <!-- empty for all or subset of items from those in yaml list -->
    <param name="temperature_sensor_set" value="" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

A subscriber is created for each sensor/topic; the `temperature_sensor_set` parameter specifies some selection of sensors (an empty string will mean process all of them). When setting up the subscriptions, each subscriber is associated with a unique identifier (that happens to be its vector index). Through the 'magic' of `boost::bind`, the identifier becomes part of the callback mechanism and allows message filtering.

Assume the following is found in class `MyClass`; I leave it to you to set up the header file and other things:

```
typedef struct SubInfo {
  ros::Subscriber sub;
  bool process;
} SubInfo;

std::vector<SubInfo> m_tempSubs;
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> m_topicToIxMap;
...
MyClass::MyClass() {
  // assumes ros::init() has been called; set up all subscribers
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  // get all the topics
  std::vector tempTopics;
  nh.getParam("temperature_sensors", tempTopics);

  // get the topic filtering list
  std::string temperatureSensorList;
  nh.param("temperature_sensor_set", temperatureSensorList, "");
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<tempTopics.size(); ++i) {
    std::string topic("/sensor/");
    topic += tempTopics[i];
    unsigned int ix = m_tempSubs.size();
    m_topicToIxMap[tempTopics[i]] = ix;
    SubInfo si;
    si.sub = nh.subscribe<TemperatureMsg>(topic, 1,
             boost::bind(&MyClass::tempCb, this, _1, ix));
    if (temperatureSensorList.empty() ||
        temperatureSensorList.find(tempTopics[i]) > 0) {
      si.process = true;
    } else {
      si.process = false;
    }
    m_tempSubs.push_back(si);
  }
}

MyClass::tempCb(const TemperatureMsg::ConstPtr &msg, unsigned int ix) {
  // 'ix' happily corresponds with the subscriber at 'tempSubs[ix]'
  if (m_tempSubs[ix].process) {
    // process the message
  }
}

MyClass::setSensor(const std::string &ts, bool on) {
  if (m_topicToIxMap.count(ts) > 0) {
    m_tempSubs[m_topicToIxMap[ts]].process = on;
  }
}
```

You can, of course, make it more clever and/or efficient:

- embed additional parameters in the `boost::bind`
- maintain a `std::map` of additional information (that may or may not also be part of the yaml configuration file)
- add other types of sensors, handled similarly, which can either run all in one node or in multiple instances of this node, depending on the launch and yaml files contents
- unsubscribe unused topics so as to never trigger the callback (you'd likely have to do some vector maintenance...I'm not sure)

No other 'boilerplate' code, configurable at runtime, mostly efficient; I think it'll fit your purposes. Also, as written, the subscriber list is fixed at startup, but since they're all in a data structure, you could modify it to add/remove items at runtime with a little more code.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2020-07-09**:
BTW, having tried this myself, unless I'm missing something, using boost::bind isn't necessary. You can just use the address of the callback as normal.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2022-06-23**:
Back when I wrote this, `boost::bind` was the accepted (only?) way to do this. Good to know it's no longer needed, thanks for the update!